# Tracing shell commands executed within shell scripts (e.g. zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command-line-interface, zsh

Given a shell script (with conditions, concatenations and interpolations) that builds and executes certain commands (in my case calls to ImageMagick's `convert` cli), is there a way to list the commands that were executed in that script? Since the script calls `convert` multiple times substituting args, I'd like to get a list like the following.

```
convert ...
convert ...
convert ...
...
```

I'm using zsh in OS X, but can switch to bash, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stick a

```
set -x
```

at the top of your script. Works in bash, should work in zsh.

Comment: If my script executes other scripts, is there a way to make this `set -x` affect all the nested contexts too? Maybe a global shell variable?

Comment: @hakunin: I do not think it is possible, but you can do `strace -f -o >(grep '^[0-9]\+ \+exec' > script.strace) /path/to/script.zsh` (I know about strace -e option, but I do not want to remember all variants of exec function). Note that it will catch only launching of external processes, it won't catch every shell command.

Comment: @hakunin: If all the scripts involved are zsh scripts, there's a way: add `set -x` to `/tmp/somedir/.zshenv` and run the script with `ZDOTDIR=/tmp/somedir /path/to/script`. For ksh scripts, set `ENV=/tmp/env.sh` where `env.sh` contains `set -x`. For bash scripts, set `BASH_ENV`.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh` (maybe only with `oh-my-zsh` enabled) I find there's a lot of noise produced with `set -x` or `setopt xtrace`.

But you can also:

```
typeset -ft <function_name>
```

to trace only one function.

To turn it off:

```
typeset +ft <function_name>
```

Adapted from the [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html).